# Which Instant Messenger services can some server side code, consume?

Tags: .net, instant-messaging

I've got an application which i want to send some alerts information. Currently, it's firing off emails -> works perfectly fine.

I was hoping to intergrate this server application with one/many Instant messenger services, such as MSN Messenger or Google Chat. I'm not sure what my options are, though.

Has anyone any information if this is possible?

Lastly, i need to do this with .NET.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also, [MSNPSharp](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp), which is strictly focused just on MSN's IM protocol.

Comment: sweet :) that's exactly what i was after for the MSN IM Protocol :) Now ... to try and figure out how to use it :(

Comment: @Pure.Krome, if you get something simple working, it'd be really useful to post it somewhere.  A sort of "Hello, World" of MSNPSharp.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) library is the most common way to do this.  That's what many of the multi-protocol clients like Adium and Pidgin and Meebo use to talk to the actual IM services like Google/jabber, Yahoo, and MSN.

This claims to be libpurple with .NET bindings:

http://code.google.com/p/libpurple-sharp/source/checkout

Comment: Hi dreeves - that's for the updated post. Um, i'm not sure what i'm suppose to do with all those files and stuff? i mean, i'm suppose to compile em .. but there's no vs2008 proj file, etc. it's like it's made for mono or something? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) is a C# library that lets you send messages over the XMPP protocol (used by Google Talk)